# Rearranging a formula containing a non-square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, least-squares

> Given $4 \times 2$ matrix $V$ and $4 \times 1$ matrix $K$, solve the linear system $V A = K$ for $A$.

If V was a square matrix I could just multiply by the inverse, but I cannot since it is not. Apparently, the solution is of the form

$$A=(V'*V)\(V' K)$$

where $V'$ is the transpose of $V$.

What is this called? The algebra seems to be out of nowhere. I know that the transpose of $V$ theoretically is cancelled out, but it seems like dividing which is not allowed in matrix algebra.

Comment: found answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797351/using-inverse-of-transpose-matrix-to-cancel-out-terms

Comment: Be careful. If $V$ is rank-deficient, then $V'V$ will not be invertible.

Comment: Note that \ is not division. It is MATLAB's command to solve a linear system using Gaussian elimination.

Comment: What is it called? It is called solving the **normal equations** via Gaussian elimination.